# What is the best way to populate and retrive the data in anguarl js from REST

Tags: angularjs, rest

In one of my SPA , user can enter data , and save data to backend and he can see previous session edited data.

view :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="student.name" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }"ng-change="save()"/>
  <input type="number" ng-model="student.age" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }"ng-change="save()"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="student.country"ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }"ng-change="save()"/>
```

**Controller**:

Rest get function :

```
StudentService.getStudentName('id10001').then(function(serverValueForID){
      $scope.student = angular.copy(serverValueForID) // get function -REST
 });
```

and save (REST put) function is :

```
$scope.save = function(){
          StudentService.setStudentName($scope.student) //put function - REST
   }
```

**Question** :

```
$scope.student = angular.copy(serverValueForID)
```

> For The above line is there any  alternative way is there to assign
>   the server data directly to view without detach the object (copy the
>   server data ) ?

Comment: Why don't you use : $scope.student = response ? (response is the $http.get response)

Comment: is there any issue wrt using angular.copy(object) ?

Comment: No issue, but I don't see why it would be necessary in this particular case.

Comment: Same opinion, is there any reason to use a copy instead of a simple variable assignment ?